# Maven Command line to execute specific TestNG testMethod

Tags: maven, automated-tests, testng, build-automation, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a requirement like I have couple of suite.xml files in a source folder

```
/src/main/suite/suite1.xml , /src/main/suite/suite2.xml
```

where each suite file contain only TestClass Names

```
Suite1.xml contains
 <test name="Sanity_Automation_Suite" preserve-order="true">
            <classes>
                <class
                    name="com.package.test.module.TestClass1" />
            </classes>
        </test>
```

---

TestClass1 has few test-methods like testMethod1(), testMethod2(), testMethod3()...

---

I have mentioned the surefire plugin in my pom.xml as below.

```
        <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

so that I can use any suite.xml file at the runtime in maven command.

When I execute the command

```
mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/main/suites/suite1.xml -Dtest=com.package.test.module.TestClass1#testMethod3()
```

I am getting below error

```
**Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project testAutomation: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)**
```

can Anyone suggest how can I achieve this with above setup.The goal I want to achieve is that, I want to execute any test-method in a testclass mentioned in my suite.xml

Comment: The syntax for `-Dtest` is testClass#testName **without** the closing brackets e.g. `com.package.test.module.TestClass1#testMethod3` instead of `com.package.test.module.TestClass1#testMethod3()`. On a side note: both `-DsuiteXmlFile` and `-Dtest` are acting as filters for tests so do you need both? If you just want to run a single test then perhaps you should just specify `-Dtest` rather than `-DsuiteXmlFile` too since applying two filters opens up the possibility of a disjoint.

Comment: If I give "mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/main/suites/suite1.xml test" it runs all the test for the class
also I use the command "mvn  test -Dtest=TestClass1#testMethod3"
I still get the exception
"Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project testAutomation: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test failed: testSuiteXmlFiles0 has null value "

Comment: Yes, you have defined the surefire plugin to always use a `suiteXmlFile` so unless you supply `-DsuiteXmlFile` you will get this response: "testSuiteXmlFiles0 has null value". If you really must use that approach then I think you'll have to invoke like this: `mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/main/suites/suite1.xml  -Dtest=TestClass1#testMethod3` and make sure that whatever test case you specifiy with -Dtest **does** exist within the given suite.

Comment: I tried the above suggestion : 
mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/main/suites/backendtsuite.xml -Dtest=SampleTestClass#testRun4

but still I am getting  "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project datastream: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)"

Comment: And you're certain that this is not because of a disjoint? i.e. `SampleTestClass` is definitely in `backendtsuite.xml`? At this stage I'd recomment stripping things back; get the `-Dtest` approach working without suiteXmlFile and then reintroduce suiteXmlFile.

Comment: Yes there is a class SampleTestClass mentioned in the backendtsuite.xml
`<suite name="Backend-Suites" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Complete Backend Suite" >
    <classes>
      <class name="com.SampleTestClass"/>
    </classes>
`
I tried but still the same issue ... I can run the command successfully
`mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/main/suites/backendtsuite.xml`
but when I intend to run a specific test 
`mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/main/suites/backendtsuite.xml -Dtest=SampleTestClass#testRun` it gives same exception

Comment: also I tried different project where it runs fine not sure whats wrong with this project.. where confused :/ now